# Bootstrap4 Carousel not swiping left and right

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am following the Bootstrap code snippet page to create the following carousel. It has three images and the controls are supposed to slide left are right. The scripts that I am using are shown in the `<script>` tags at the bottom of the file.

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wantrepreneur</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  <header>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <!-- Slide One - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/LAaSoL0LrYs/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">First Slide</h2>
            <p class="lead">This is a description for the first slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Two - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/bF2vsubyHcQ/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">Second Slide</h2>
            <p class="lead">This is a description for the second slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Slide Three - Set the background image for this slide in the line below -->
        <div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/szFUQoyvrxM/1920x1080')">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h2 class="display-4">Third Slide</h2>
            <p class="lead">This is a description for the third slide.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <section class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4">Full Page Image Slider</h1>
      <p class="lead">The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The images in this snippet are from <a href="https://unsplash.com">Unsplash</a>, taken by <a href="https://unsplash.com/@joannakosinska">Joanna Kosinska</a>!</p>
    </div>
  </section>

<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

However, when I press either of the controls, the link in my browser changes from `link.com` to `link.com#carouselExampleIndicators`, but nothing happens and the images don't slide/change. What should I do to fix this?

Thanks,
Vinny

Comment: It looks like you are loading Bootstrap before jQuery. Try switching your script order.

Comment: worked. make an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Glad it worked! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple script order issue. Bootstrap needs jQuery, but you are loading Bootstrap before jQuery. Switch the order:

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before release of bootstrap 5,

In **`Bootstrap < 5`** is dependent on **`jQuery`**:-

so, you have to maintain the order of the external scripts in your html code:-

It should be:-

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```